How to store a value returned by a Robot Framework Keyword to a variable in a python (.py) file
I have created a .robot file which generates and returns an Item number (any random number) and it gets stored in a robot framework variable.e.g.
${item_number} =  123456789 
I want to get that value stored in ${item_number} variable and use that in a .py file which I am using to add data in an excel sheet
#Library to import current date and time
import datetime

#Library for Excel
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook

#Opening active excel
book = openpyxl.load_workbook('New_SO_CA.xlsx')
sheet = book.active

#Adding data to Excel Sheet
sheet['D2'] = ''      #This is where I want to use the ${item_number} value

Excel sheet should get updated like the following:



Column D2




123456789



Please let me know if I have missed something to add. Thanks in advance.
I have tried to look online but I only found how to manually add a value in the python file to store it in the excel sheet or to dynamically update value in robot file using python file.

I guess it is possible using the Run Process keyword and passing the variable as argument for your python code.

I updated the code as per your suggestion but Open Excel Document Keyword is not being recognized. I have imported the Excel Library and it has been installed as well.

This is currently working for me.
test.py:
#Library to import current date and time
import datetime
import sys      

#Library for Excel
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook

#Opening active excel
book = openpyxl.load_workbook('New_SO_CA.xlsx')
sheet = book.active

#Adding data to Excel Sheet
myData = int(sys.argv[1])  # The list of command line arguments passed to a Python script
sheet['D2'] = myData      #This is where I want to use the ${item_number} value

# Saving the changes to the file
book.save('New_SO_CA.xlsx')

testRobot.robot:
*** Settings ***
Library        Process
Library        ExcelLibrary


*** Variables ***
${ITEMNUMBER}        123456789


*** Test Cases ***
Verify the addition of data
    Run Process            python.exe    test.py      ${ITEMNUMBER}
    Open Excel Document    filename=New_SO_CA.xlsx    doc_id=myData
    ${item}                Read Excel Cell            row_num=2    col_num=4     sheet_name=Sheet1
    ${converted}           Convert To String          ${item}
    Should Be Equal        first=${ITEMNUMBER}        second=${converted}

Using Run Process    python.exe    test.py    ${ITEMNUMBER}, I was able to execute the python script. Additionally I used the ExcelLibrary to verify that the given value and value in D2 cell matches.
Hope this helps!

Could not make it work but found a work around by storing item number as text in a .txt file and then read its contents and saved in the .xlsx file. The links that helped me are link1  and link2. Thanks for all your help @Pramesh, cheers. Please let me know if you get a chance to find why I was getting the error 'No Keyword found 'Open Excel Document''. Cheers.

I have updated the code as per your suggestion @Parmesh and getting the error 'No keyword with name 'Open Excel Document' found.'
Screenshot of the excel library installed:
installed excel library
test.py:
#Library to import current date and time
import datetime

#Library for Excel
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook

#Library to generate random numbers
import random
from random import randint

# Generating and Storing Current date and time
x = datetime.datetime.now()
Datetime = (x.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S"))

#Generating and storing random number
n = random.randint(1111, 9999999)

#Opening active excel
book = openpyxl.load_workbook('New_SO_CA.xlsx')
sheet = book.active

#Adding data to Excel Sheet
myData = int(sys.argv[1])  # The list of command line arguments passed to a Python script
sheet['D2'] = myData 
sheet['E2'] = 4
sheet['G2'] = n

#Saving excel in given path
book.save('New_SO_CA.xlsx')

testRobot.robot
*** Settings ***
Library        Process
Library        ExcelLibrary


*** Variables ***
${ITEMNUMBER}        123456789


*** Test Cases ***
Verify the addition of data
    Run Process            python.exe    test.py      ${ITEMNUMBER}
    Open Excel Document    filename=New_SO_CA.xlsx    doc_id=myData
    ${item}                Read Excel Cell            row_num=2    col_num=4     sheet_name=Sheet1
    ${converted}           Convert To String          ${item}
    Should Be Equal        first=${ITEMNUMBER}        second=${converted}

Please let me know if you would need more information related to the error.

You need to install the library using pip install robotframework-excellib

It is already installed, I have attached the screen shot too in my answer. My previous code was working though where I was adding static value to the excel sheet from my python file. I also figured that the command line arguments part of the .py file is not being executed but as soon as I remove that part my script runs fine.
